# MVC 4 - Invalid ModelState

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Im getting some errors through my app of an Invalid ModelState, however Im struggling to reproduce this issue locally as its always valid.

I've narrowed it down to a DateTime object however When I submit with a null date the model is valid (thats fine because I dont have a required rule set)

However some users are triggering the !IsValid to fire, their DateTime is null, just like mine)

Could it be certain browsers?

ViewModel

```
 public class Client
    {
public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Form

```
 <input type="date" id="DateOfBirth" value="@Model.DateOfBirth" class="form-control" tabindex="3" name="DateOfBirth" />
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult New(ViewModels.Client client)
        {

 if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
//Dosomething send error message
}
```

}

Any ideas?

Comment: Try searching. DateTime formatting and the influence of server/client locales thereon have been thoroughly documented. At least read [ask] and include the actual error (not "some errors") in your question and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class Client
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I dont want it required tho